# Как в WooCommerce удалить товар из истории заказов

Tags: php, woocommerce

В Личном Кабинете пользователь может отменить бронирование отеля. Я написал функцию, которая удаляет нужный номер из базы данных. Нужно, чтобы из самого заказа этот товар тоже удалился и цена пересчиталась. Наверняка, есть готовые решения. В Google ничего не нашёл, что бы мне подошло. Сайт на WordPress. Требуется решение в рамках WooCommerce.

Comment: написать запрос в БД  на который сработает триггер, а тот будет запускать процедуру на пересчет?

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо! Вопрос решён